# Oracle Identity Manager PS3 REST API

Tags: api, rest, soa, identity, oim

I am trying to approve/reject an user role assignment request using REST APIs in PS3. I am good to do so with approve. But, rejection is not happening since I need to update the comment too while rejecting any approval. Can anybody help me to get the REST APIs configured in HTTPRequestHeader or RestClient (Mozilla addon for testing REST API). Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try using postman